# yesterday my blog stopped working and showing a fatal error

Tags: wordpress, blogs

Fatal error: Class 'WP_Recovery_Mode_Link_Service' not found in /home/test/public_html/blog/wp-login.php on line 522

Getting an error like this. Can someone please help me to sort out this?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the default theme to activate and hopefully rule-out a theme-specific issue. [Read more](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-uncaught-error-class-wp_recovery_mode_link_service-not-found/)